# Struct, linked list,delete the whole list

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list

How can I delete all objects from a linked list,implemented in struct? After my delete-funktion (loeschen) are shown comic numbers and I don´t know any more where my pointers are.

```
struct domino {
int data1;
int data2;
domino *next;


};

int readSteine (){ //Reading from numbers from file
    FILE *file;


    if((file=fopen("datei.dat", "r") )==NULL) { /
        std::cout<<"File cant be open"<<std::endl;
        return 0;
    }else {
        int beginning;
        int temp;
        fscanf(file, "%d", &beginning);

        for(int i=0; i<beginning; i++) {
            domino *domino1= new domino;
             //if(i>0) temp2->next=domino1; 
            fscanf(file, "%i", &temp);
            domino1->data1=temp;
            fscanf(file, "%i", &temp);
            domino1->data2=temp;
            printf("[%d:%d]", domino1->data1, domino1->data2);
            domino1->next=0;
       }
    }return 0;
}
```

Function for deleting of the list:

```
void deletelist (domino *head) {
    domino* tmp;
    while(head != 0) { 
        tmp=head->next;
        delete head;
        head=tmp;
    }

}


int main() {
    domino *pHead=NULL; 
domino s;
    readSteine();
    deletelist(pHead);
    std::cout<<s.data1<<"...."<<s.data2<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Diana. First, you need to pass your Kopf to the readSteine funktion, and assign it to each new next, and after that assign to it the new domino, and so on to form the linked list..

Comment: @ACV while it may help us understand the problem quicker, it definitely won't help OP to learn C++ in a foreign language.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of a clear method. The idea is to traverse over the list and delete the nodes one by one.

```
Node *pDel = _pHead;

    /* Traverse the list and delete the node one by one from the head */
    while (pDel != NULL) {
        /* take out the head node */
        _pHead = _pHead->_pNext;
        delete pDel;
        /* update the head node */
        pDel = _pHead;
    }
    /* Reset the head and tail node */
    _pTail = _pHead = NULL;
```

Answer (score -1):

Define the function either like

```
void loeschen (dominostein **kopf) {
    dominostein* tmp;
    while(*kopf != 0) { //bzw. NULL
        tmp = ( *kopf )->next;
        delete *kopf;
        *kopf = tmp;
    }
}
```

and call it like

```
loeschen(&pKopf);
```

or the following way

```
void loeschen (dominostein * &kopf) {
    dominostein* tmp;
    while( kopf != 0) { //bzw. NULL
        tmp = ( kopf )->next;
        delete kopf;
        kopf = tmp;
    }
}
```

and call it like

```
loeschen(pKopf);
```

Your original function also is correct but after deleteing all nodes

```
loeschen(pKopf);
```

you should set `pKopf` to NULL

```
pKopf = NULL;
```

Or you simply should not use this pointer to access the deleted nodes.:)

Take into account that this statement

```
std::cout<<s.data1<<"...."<<s.data2<<std::endl;
```

does not make sense because data members `data1` and `data2` of object `s` were not inistilaized when the object was created

```
domino s;
```

And this object has nothing common with the list.

And function `readSteine` does not use node `pHead` defined in main

```
domino *pHead=NULL; 
//...
readSteine();
```

You shpuld rewrite the function. It is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Your loeschen will never works becouse you pass to it just a NULL.
You first need to correctly construct the list. First, you need to pass your Kopf (a kind of reference to it) to the readSteine function, and assign it to each new next, and after that assign to it the new domino, and so on to form the linked list..

I strongly recommend you to read  [Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++](http://www.amazon.de/Programming-Principles-Practice-Using-C/dp/0321992784/ref=pd_cp_14_3?ie=UTF8&refRID=0M3CK94F0B4QT6327Y8D) .

You mix C functions and style of programming with C++. You dont even need to know these C functions which are hard to learn right in order to begin to learn C++.

Comment: Down-vote because it isn't an answer. Should have been a comment (even though it would take a few comments to fit it all...)

Comment: @EvanCarslake . Are you sure?  How is not this the correct answer? Did yuo read the Q? Why nothing is deleted? Why the comic "-rare" output? The delete function is ok.